# Access two one index of multiindex DataFrame

Tags: python, pandas

I look for accessing to all elements where the second index equal 'P0 (YI)' but my command doesn't work.
Can somebody help me ?

```
>>> G11
<class 'pandas.core.frame.DataFrame'>
MultiIndex: 10000 entries, (s0000, Averaging) to (s0999, P0 (YI))
Data columns (total 3 columns):
Volume    10000  non-null values
dtypes: float64(3)

>>> G11.ix[(:,'P0 (YI)')]
  File "<stdin>", line 1
    G11.ix[(:,'P0 (YI)')]
            ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

Comment: use ``df.xs('P0 (YI)',level=1)``; The syntax that you *want* will be available in 0.14, see here: http://pandas-docs.github.io/pandas-docs-travis/whatsnew.html#multiindexing-using-slicers

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `G11.xs('P0 (YI)',level=1)`

The syntax that you are suggesting will be available in 0.14, see [here](http://pandas-docs.github.io/pandas-docs-travis/whatsnew.html#multiindexing-using-slicers)

Answer (score 0):

try

```
G11.xs('P0 (YI)', level=1)
```